# compileKotlin block in build.gradle file throws error "Could not find method compileKotlin() for arguments [...]"

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to configure Kotlin to work with Java 1.8 in my Android project. I've tried adding the `compileKotlin` block at the bottom of my `build.gradle` file, but I get an error if I do so.

The error that occurs is the following:

> Error:(38, 0) Could not find method compileKotlin() for arguments
>   [build_dvcqiof5pov8xt8flfud06cm3$_run_closure4@66047120] on project
>   ':core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

The project runs fine without this block. What am I missing? Here's the complete `build.gradle` file, it's pretty basic stuff:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileKotlin {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        apiVersion = '1.1'
        languageVersion = '1.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The error you are getting means that there's no `compileKotlin` task in the project, and that's expected for Android projects.

The Kotlin compilation task names in Android projects contain the [build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) names (those are combined from build type, product flavor and other settings and look like `debug` or `releaseUnitTest` -- the tasks are `compileDebugKotlin` and `compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin` respectively). There's no `compileKotlin` task, which is usually created for the `main` source set in ordinary Java + Kotlin projects.

Most probably, you want to configure *all* Kotlin compilation tasks in the project, and to do that, you can apply the block as follows:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        apiVersion = '1.1'
        languageVersion = '1.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, I thought compileKotlin was applied to all build variants but apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: in which file and where we need to put these lines

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J, you can put them in the `build.gradle` file of the project's modules. For example, in an Android project with a single module `app`, put them into `app/build.gradle`. Just append them in the end of the file to make sure the Kotlin plugin has already been applied when they are reached.

Comment: Should be `tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class)`

Comment: @Diolor This is how I do it: `tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> { ... }`

Comment: Use the `kotlin-android` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418991/9636

Comment: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'org' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension. or Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'org' for project ':XXX' of type org.gradle.api.Project. if used in the gradle outside android

Comment: @EntangledLoops I get Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Answer (score 47):

From the [kotlin-android documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/Module.md#kotlin-android):

Android plugin also adds *kotlinOptions* extension to android section to set options for all kotlin tasks:

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        noStdlib = true
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer!

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: base_android_configuration_2j7ahxwm32c8n4wt5ejh7kbub.android() is applicable for argument types: (base_android_configuration_2j7ahxwm32c8n4wt5ejh7kbub$_run_closure1) values: [base_android_configuration_2j7ahxwm32c8n4wt5ejh7kbub$_run_closure1@64c6e15e]

Answer (score 8):

Not a direct answer to the question, but Google led me to this answer when experiencing the same `compileKotlin block in build.gradle file throws error “Could not find method compileKotlin() for arguments […]”` error.

In my case the problem was caused by importing a code module to my project that contained only Java code. The fix was to ensure the following is in the Java-specific module's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: This is what worked for me! I added it at the top of the `app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 6):

android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
       // ADDED
       kotlin_version = "1.8.22"
    }
}
dependencies {
    // ADDED
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

android\app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
        // ADDED
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget=11
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In some projects I've Just used **refresh gradle dependencies** and solved the problem:

Right click on project's name and select **refresh gradle dependencies**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those like me that are struggling with gradles, these at least compile:

**Top-level project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.8.22"
        appcompat_version = "1.6.1"
        google_services_version = "4.3.15"
        maps_version = "18.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.22' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
// app build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.test.foobar'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.foobar"
        minSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets{
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$maps_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know sounds weird but I solved my problem with this solution. Android Studio recommends some improvements such as "*Remove Explicit Type Arguments*" but when I do it, I got this error.

So, my suggestion is that please add your "***Explicit Type Arguments***", then try again.

Explicit Type Arguments Example:
[image]