# Android Studio throws build error in Kotlin project which calls static method in java interface

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project in Android Studio. I am calling a static method in Java interface from the Kotlin code. The build fails with the error,

```
Calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'
```

[image: Error]

I have the following in my **build.gradle**,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I have also changed the Target JVM version to 1.8 in Kotlin compiler settings. Still, the build throws the error. Also tried Invalidating cache and restarting.

[image: Kotlin Compiler Settings]

Android Studio version: 3.0.1

Comment: in android studio try **File** > **Invalidate Cashes & Restart...**

Comment: Tried that. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 11):

Proper way to set Kotlin compile options in android gradle.
Make these changes to your app level **Build.gradle**

Change

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

to

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
```

Then write this task

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        apiVersion = '1.1'
        languageVersion = '1.1'
    }
}
```

just below(not necessarily)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

For details, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143253/5689605)

Answer (score 5):

The `compileOptions` section in build.gradle affects the Java compiler, not the Kotlin compiler. To set the target JVM version for the Kotlin compiler, use the following block:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

See [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) for more information.

Comment: I added the following code to my root build.grade file, Still getting the same error. 

 `plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.21"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I had a folder for the integration tests different than the unit test folder. So the build.gradle needs more configuration:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
} 
//added this
compileIntegrationTestKotlin {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to resolve this by adding below block as my build.gradle is not in dsl. To set the target JVM version for the Kotlin compiler, use the following block:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```