# Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm, corda

When trying to run the Example CorDapp ([GitHub CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example)) via IntelliJ, I receive the following error:

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is
> being built with JVM target 1.6

How can I modify the IntelliJ settings so that all the bytecode is built with the same JVM target?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding this library to `build.gradle`
dependencies {
compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
}

Comment: @MunishChandel That is not sufficient.  We must also do what the answer below suggests...

Comment: Had the same error when specifying jvmTarget = "15" on Linux but the same project was working on Windows, both on IntelliJ 2020.3. Changed to jvmTarget = "14" and it worked on both. In either case there were no errors from the command line, only in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

You can fix this issue as follows:

- Open the IntelliJ preferences
- Go to `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Kotlin Compiler` **BUT** `Other Settings` > `Kotlin compiler` if Android Studio > `3.4`
- Change the `Target JVM version` to `1.8`
- Click `Apply`

Comment: I have this setting fixed to 1.8 already, yet I still see this error when stepping through breakpoints. I primarily see this when hitting vault queries. Any further suggestions? It seems this target JVM bit doesn't fix it entirely.

Comment: On your **Project Structure**, make sure you also change the `Target platform` to **JVM 1.8** on your `Kotlin` Facet under the `General` tab.

Comment: Would you know the instructions to do the same on eclipse?

Comment: And after Apply restart IDE.

Comment: This error can appear if there is an **unresolved dependency**!

Comment: For me the `Kotlin Compiler` settings were actually placed in `Other Settings` section.

Comment: If restarting after apply is not enough → Restart & Invalidate caches.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work if you have multiple modules. In that case you need to add 
``` kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```
for every gradle in a module

Comment: You should go to Kotlin Compiler

Comment: kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

Comment: I do not see `General` Tab or `Build, Execution, Deployment` on Android Studio though.

Comment: As others have said, it was already set to 1.8 in the settings. Adding `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" } ` in the build.gradle (Module: app) fixed it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Solved my problem with `kotlinOptions`

Comment: The above did not help me. I had to add the below to Module gradle.build file:
` 
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        apiVersion = '1.1'
        languageVersion = '1.1'
    }
}
` 
from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141076/compilekotlin-block-in-build-gradle-file-throws-error-could-not-find-method-com

Answer (score 1541):

### app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

GL

[Use Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Comment: As of this date and Android Studio v3.5 this is the only solution that worked, after trying all the rest. Strangely enough setting the same value in Settings > Kotlin Compiler has no effect.

Comment: Just the `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }` should suffice.

Comment: @petter Some libraries need both options such as `okhttp3:logging-interceptor` to use `OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor`

Comment: kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

Comment: Then should "invalidate cache and restart"

Comment: I had already define the compileOption but not kotlinOption after define kotlinOption error gone. Its work for me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: And what if this is not for android? Where do the `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions` go?

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch What context are you referring to?

Comment: Why some people wrap this kotlinOptions { } inside a tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all { } ?

Comment: @LeonardoSibela In Gradle is that everything is executed against a Interface Project instance.

These are tasks executed in the global instance of gradle, that is, at the level of the project module. So this configuration loses sense modularization since it configures all the existing build.gradle in the project.

Comment: If you're trying to inline 1.8 bytecode in another Gradle module, you should also put this code in another module too (not just `app`)

Comment: Of course, the scope of the gradle is for the module unless you run tasks on the global gradle instance.

Answer (score 151):

you should configure something like as follows in build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, in the Gradle Kotlin DSL: `tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8" }`

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work with `kotlin-android` plugin?

Comment: Works without much hassle. I'd recommend it

Comment: I had this in build.gradle, but somehow IDEA overwrote this setting. The Answer from Saeed worked for me.

Comment: Do add this in your app-level Gradle's android {} section.

Comment: I get error "A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'org' for project ':subprojectName' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: @Amuthan, could you please include @ Parag Kadam's remark in your answer? it's essential

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason the highly upvoted answer that puts this inside an `android` block gives me an unresolved reference error.

Answer (score 121):

please add this code to android section inside your app/build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: its working great can you please explain it, why we need to do this and whats its mean.

Comment: it works, when my destination fragment was not able to accept  navArgs() and was complaining about inline bytecode built. My app gradle had compile options for source and target but i didnt have kotlinOptions. After i added Kotlin options and clean PRoject> Rebuild Project. worked fine.

Comment: It doesn't differ from the top answer.

Answer (score 90):

In my case, just changingTarget JVM Version like this:  File > Setting > Kotlin Compiler > Target JVM Version > 1.8 did not help. However, it does resolved compile time error. But failed at runtime.

I also had to add following in app build.gradle file to make it work.

```
 android {
     // Other code here...
     kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
     }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 65):

When the other solutions did not work for you (Changing JVM version on Compiler settings and adding `jvmTarget` into your `build.gradle`), because of your `.iml` files trying to force their configurations you can change the target platform from Project Settings.

- Open `File > Project Structure`
- Go to `Facets` under `Project Settings`

  - If it is empty then click on the small `+` button
- Click on your Kotlin module/modules
- Change the `Target Platform` to `JVM 1.8` (also it's better to check `Use project settings` option)

Comment: I can't find this or the 'facets' section in Android Studio...  I had to edit the app.iml manually. I set ```<configuration version="3" platform="JVM 1.8" useProjectSettings="false">``` to `true` and it worked. However, the file keeps changing back!

Comment: @Aphex It's actually under "File" > "Project Structure" then under "Project Settings" >  "Facets", I had nothing there, so I cliked "+" > "Kotlin" > Select my project. That did it for me :)

Comment: This works for me, but being forced back to 1.6 every time I add to my build.gradle.kts file.

Comment: Is there a way to have this configured and picked up from the gradle file? IMHO this being misconfigured is a bug in intellij.

Answer (score 63):

In my case this code didn't work until I moved `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` from bottom to top.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    } 
Didi the trick for me, thx

Answer (score 34):

In Android Studio 4.3.2 adding through the below procedure is not working.

1. Open the IntelliJ preferences
2. Go to **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Compiler** > **Kotlin Compiler** BUT Other Settings > Kotlin compiler if Android Studio > 3.4
3. Change the **Target JVM version** to 1.8
4. Click Apply

The reason is, Android studio is unable to add the below code in the module level Gradle file. Please add it manually.

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Just for the addon, search **Target JVM version** in the android studio search. It will take you directly to the option.
[image]

Comment: only by adding manually, it worked for me. For some reason, android studio is really buggy and it does not consider changes applied unless we restart the ide by deleting all cache.

Comment: Tnx, your solution worked for me, although I needed to restart android studio to make it reconfigure project!

Answer (score 29):

**Feb 2020** 
*android 3.4+*
Go to File -> Settings -> Kotlin Compiler -> Target JVM Version > set to 1.8 and then make sure to do File -> Sync project with Gradle files
Or add this into **build.gradle(module:app)** in **android** block:

```
kotlinOptions {
           jvmTarget = "1.8"
         }
```

Comment: confirmed that you need to do File -> Sync project with Gradle files, then it works

Answer (score 28):

If you have many sourcesets/modules it can be cumbersome to configure the jvmTarget for each of them separately.

You can configure the jvmTarget for all of them at once like so:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

This snippet can be used on top level of your gradle.build file

After modifying the gradle file `Reimport All Gradle Imports`.
To check if it worked, open `Project Structure` and verify that IntelliJ correctly assigned `JVM 1.8` to all Kotlin-Modules. It should look like this:

[image: project structure]

I would **not** recommend changing the platform directly in IntelliJ, because anyone else cloning your project for the first time is likely to face the same issue. Configuring it correctly in gradle has the advantage that IntelliJ is going to behave correctly for them right from the start.

Answer (score 25):

As it is written in the [using-maven](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) docs from the Kotlin website:

You just have to put `<kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>` into the properties section of your pom.xml

Comment: After trying everything, yours was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 24):

In my case, jvmTarget was already set in `build.gradle` file as below.

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But my issue was still there.
Finally, it gets resolved after Changing Target JVM version from 1.6 to 1.8 in Preferences > Other Settings > Kotlin Compiler > Target JVM version. see attached picture,

[image]

Comment: Great Help, you saved my day too, Thanks

Answer (score 21):

This helped my project to build, add this to module build.gradle file:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

For me the reason was this configuration in my build gradle was in some modules and in some it wasnt

```
android {  
...      
kotlinOptions {
        val options = this as KotlinJvmOptions
        options.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
...
android {
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that worked for me. I am using kts buiild files.

Comment: Thanks, this is also the solutions that worked for me. And much declarative this way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041765/3763032 kevin also stated this, due to the smartcast in kotlin gradle files .kts it is available directly

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I solved this by following these two steps

```
1. Go to android studio preferences -> other settings -> kotlin compiler -> set Target JVM version = 1.8 
   if it doesn't work then go to the second option.

2. In your module-level build.gradle file add 
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I had to do the 2nd step, and its working. Can you explain why it is needed?

Comment: you can find more details on this closed issue it's good to know [https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics/issues/454]

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

For Gradle with Kotlin language (`*.gradle.kts` files), add this:

```
android {
    [...]
    kotlinOptions {
        this as KotlinJvmOptions
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to cast `this` to `KotlinJvmOptions`. Isn't the `this` receiver in the `kotlinOptions` block already `KotlinJvmOptions`?
Still it doesn't work for me without the cast

Comment: @11m0, I think it's related to this issue: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1368

Comment: When KotlinJvmOptions is not found, try using the full name "org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions".

Answer (score 13):

The next solution helped me. Add to build.gradle

```
 compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Useful if you are using this without android

Answer (score 9):

in most cases this is enough:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

if you have declared custom Gradle tasks like `integrationTest` for example, add a configuration for `compile<YourTaskName>Kotlin` as well:

```
compileIntegrationTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: this would work too  by adding to gradle file --> compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    } kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

Comment: interestingly, only your solution worked with my non-android module! thanks!

Answer (score 9):

All answers here are using gradle but if someone like me ends up here and needs answer for maven:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>11</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The change from jetbrains archetype for kotlin-jvm is the `<configuration></configuration>` specifying the jvmTarget. In my case 11

Answer (score 7):

Setting `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` enables desugaring, but it is currently unable to desugar all the Java 8 features that the Kotlin compiler uses.

[image]

Fix - Setting `kotlinOptions.jvmTarget to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` in the app module Gradle would fix the issue.

> Use Java 8 language features:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  // For Kotlin projects
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You may need to set both `compileKotlin` and `compileTestKotlin`.
This works on gradle 6.5.1.

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.2"
        apiVersion = "1.2"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.2"
        apiVersion = "1.2"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Kotlin and Gradle for normal JVM development, (not android) and this worked for me in `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with React Native Android, Thanks

Answer (score 6):

if you are in android project

in your app's build.gradle
under android{}

```
android{
//other configs...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I did all steps but didn't success the problem was

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32'
```

when I updated to

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30'
```

shows that problem when I back to

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32'
```

the problem fixed

Comment: After rebuilding my project it states with this error message "This version (1.0.3) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.30 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.32 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!)."

Answer (score 5):

Using the Kotlin Gradle DSL, this solved the issue for me. I added this to the build.gradle.kts.
This is in addition to the answer by [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620025/joel)

```
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
```

Comment: Can you please share where exactly in the file you put this? And which version of the android plugin and gradle you are using?

Comment: This is not an Android project. I am running Gradle 6.4.

Answer (score 5):

If non of the above answers works, you can do this in kotlin dsl

```
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
}
```

Comment: The `android` block is redundant. The `tasks` property comes from the Gradle `project`.

Answer (score 4):

If using Visual Studio Code** with Kotlin extension, go to the plugin management Crtl + Shift + x, type kotlin and click on manage (the little gear) >> Configure Extension Settings

on Kotlin >> Compiler >> Jvm:Target - type the java version. In my situation just typed 1.8

And then restart :-)

** vscode or just 'code' for linux

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me until I updated my kotlin plugin dependency.
Try this:
1. Invalidate cahce and restart.
2. Sync project (at least try to)
3. Go **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Suggestions**
4. If there is an update regarding Kotlin, update it.
Hope it will help someone.

Comment: the easiest fix

Answer (score 2):

If you use Eclipse assuming you downloaded the Kotlin plugin:

Right click project -> Properties -> Kotlin Compiler -> Enable project specific settings -> JVM target version "1.8"

Answer (score 2):

In my case **File > Setting > Kotlin Compiler > Target JVM Version > 1.8**

Answer (score 1):

For recent versions of Android Studio, if changing just the Kotlin Target VM version didn't work.

File ➞ Project Structure ➞ Modules (`app`): set both "Source Compatibility" and "Target Compatibility" to "1.8 (Java 8)". Press "OK" and sync project with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

If you'r facing this message in a Spring Boot/Kotlin project, just set the property "kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget" to "1.8" in your pom.xml.

```
    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.70</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
    </properties>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another hint for Eclipse users. After double checking the jvm target settings pointed out by other users, I still had the same problem, and that was caused by missing Kotlin Runtime Library. For eg, when creating a project with spring initializr, it is not added automatically. For adding it: `right click on your project -> Build path -> Add libraries... -> User Library`, and simply add `org.jetbrains.kotlin.core.KOTLIN_CONTAINER`

Make sure you refresh your gradle project afterwards (`right click -> Gradle -> Refresh gradle project`)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked changing from `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30'` to `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32'`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by navigating to the `gradle.build` file, and updating the version of the kotlin plugin.

For me, originally the configuration was:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

So I changed the plugin's version to the latest available:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the answers from this page, the only thing that worked for me was to use **jvmTarget = '11'** :

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' (or any other java version that suits you)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had different versions of spring boot installed.  Presumably one was built with 17 and wasn't compatible.  But, when I downgraded the version to something known to work (2.5.14), everything worked again.

Answer (score -3):

Just add in build.gradle module this code `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }`

Comment: This has already been mentioned in many other answers.