# How do I set the jvm target for android studio using gradle and kotlin?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I get the following error when trying to compile a unit test written in kotlin.

`Task :app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin FAILED  ...Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.7 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`

I've tried setting the source compatibility for my `android` configuration in my app `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

as well as configuring all kotlin compile tasks in the root `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246275/4694013

Comment: @ZeroDivide can you please mark as correct answer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58094987/5040556

Answer (score 42):

This is a temporary Android Studio bug.
I needed to add these lines to the app's gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like this "temporary" bug is still there nine months later.

Comment: I only needed to add the kotlinOptions portion to work around it in my project.

Answer (score 13):

1)On a Mac

**Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> **Kotlin Compiler** -> Change **Target JVM version**

2) PC

**Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Settings** -> **Kotlin Compiler** -> Change **Target JVM version**

Comment: That is set to `1.8`, and shouldn't affect the `gradle` build.

Comment: Why wouldn't it affect the Gradle build? What is its purpose then? Also... I tried this setting and it had no effect on this error. I can't find where 1.6 is being specified.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but it's not woking on Android Studio 4.0.1. The alert continuos showing as red code. When I specify in build.gradle(app) finally stop showing those red code suggestions.

Comment: I am not a person.

Answer (score 3):

The [default target JVM bytecode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options) is 1.6.
But this can be set by changing build.gradle(:app):

```
android{
...
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 1.8
    }
}
```

It seems, the Android Studio Kotlin compiler target JVM option does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this in `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-Xjvm-default=enable'
    ]
  }
```

}