# What do I need to import to use launchActivity<>() in UnitTests?

Tags: android, android-testing, androidx

So I'm trying to test my activity following googles instructions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing

But the code `launchActivity<MyActivity>()`  does not work.  Do I need to define launchActivity as a rule or is there a library I need to import in gradle?

These are the imports I already have

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
```

Comment: That should be a global or extension function in Kotlin that you would import. Android Studio should offer to import it for you if you have it in one of your dependencies. Which [AndroidX test dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies) are you using?

Comment: I've added what test implementations I have in gradle.

Comment: Try adding `androidx.test:core-ktx:1.1.0`, as that is part of Android KTX, where Kotlin-specific stuff goes. Also, I recommend switching `runner` to `1.1.0` instead of `1.1.0-alpha4` and switching `espresso-core` to `3.1.1` instead of `3.1.0-alpha4`. https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html contains a list of all of the artifacts and their available versions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Do I need to define launchActivity as a rule or is there a library I
>   need to import in gradle?

Yes. You'll need to set up a rule at the beginning of your test class like this;

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class YourActivityTests extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> mYourActivityActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<YourActivity>(YourActivity.class);
```

The required library imports are bundled in import androidx.test package.

This is for Java, but, there should be an equivalent way in Kotlin. Hope this helps.

Edit: You should use the *latest* **stable builds** (the ones with only numbers in versioning) for production apps. Only use any -alpha or -rc suffixed versions when you *really* need those versions of the library.

Comment: The question is asking about a different launchActivity() than the one you are referring to. You are referring to ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(), but the Google Dev link is using a function defined in androidx.test:core-ktx.

Answer (score 25):

You need to import following dependency into your gradle.

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.1.0'`

Moreover, also add this in gradle file to avoid [compile time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988778/cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode-that-is-being-bui) after adding `launchActivity` method in your test code.

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
```

Comment: `testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.1.0'` works for unit tests

Comment: @temnoi it won't be accessible for instrument unit tests.

Answer (score 13):

In Kotlin it seems that it needs to be like this for some reason:

```
val activityScenario = launch(MainActivity::class.java)
```

The import statement for this is:

```
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch
```

Or maybe it's not the same thing? Don't know, but it works.

Comment: It works!!. In kotlin, I use it like this `@Before fun setup() {
        launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    }`