# how to get viewModel by viewModels? (fragment-ktx)

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewmodel

I am working with Single viewModel for the Activity and all of its fragment.

So to initialise `viewmodel` if have to write this setup code in `onActivityCreated` of all the fragment's

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

I was going thorough the Android KTX extension page:([refer here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment))

and i found i can initialise view model like this:

```
    // Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to this Fragment
    val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

    // Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to its Activity
    val viewModel by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()
```

So I added below dependency's to my gradle(app):

```
    //ktx android
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

But when i try to use `viewModels/activityViewModels` in my application their reference in not found.

I want help in how to use these extension's with some basic example i tried searching for examples haven't found any.

Comment: Does your ViewModel take any parameter, like repository or db?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes it does.I am working with single VM shared between all fragment.

Comment: You'd need a `ViewModelFactory` then

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Atlast we  we have got stable version.

After moving to `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'` i faced another issue.

#### Compiler Error:

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is
> being built with JVM target 1.6

#### `build.gradle` (Module `:app`)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56996020/7972699)

After applying all the above the issue's is resolved.

Comment: I am working in a multiple module app, Is there a better way then declaring this compileOption into each and every module.

Comment: @VikasPandey compileOption can be used in the global project build.gradle.

Answer (score 70):

try

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta02'
```

#### 2021 UPDATE

This is no longer in beta. It works with the latest stable version at the time of writing. You will also need to import it in your fragment's Kotlin file.

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2'
```

```
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
```

Comment: I am not sure if i want to move my project to beta version.

Comment: `by viewModels` can only be called in Fragment, or in activity as well?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This delegate can only be called from the Fragment. But if you add `implementation the "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0"` dependency, you can use a similar delegate for the Activity.

Comment: @Anmol The version in the answer graduated to Stable recently. You need to be at least on 1.1.0 for `by ViewModels()`

Comment: @MowDownJoe thank for the update and now the issue is fixed

Comment: @DenysMakhov There is no such thing as `androidx.activity:activity-ktx`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity

Comment: I got it to work when I used activity-ktx 1.1.0 and extended FragmentActivity() not just Activity()

Comment: @DenysMakhov Wrong. `fragment-ktx` works for both activity and fragment.

Comment: @Dr.jacky Yes, maybe something has changed in a YEAR.

Comment: `by viewModels()` is enough in Activity because you already in the activity, and if you need activity's viewmodel in fragment, use `by activityViewModels()`

Comment: @DenysMakhov I had this confusion and gone through the docs to see if there is a separate ktx for Activities :/

Answer (score 35):

I think you  need to have this dependency for your activity if you want to use kotlin delegations for viewmodel

```
//ViewModels delegation extentensions for activity
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for me.

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: This library works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 19):

#### UPDATE 2024 FEBRUARY 15

You should use this:

**Groovy**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2"
}
```

**Kotlin KTS**

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")
}
```

more information:

1. https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment
2. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. i.e. please [edit] your answer to say *why* this is preferred as of April 2022.

Comment: @Adriaan suggested the right thing. It would be better if the main sample references rather than sharing just web links for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You use this latest alpha version:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note : This works for Jetpack Compose too**

Copy the dependency from [HERE](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity)

Currently `2021 June 5` the dependency is as below :

```
dependencies {
    val activity_version = "1.2.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version")
    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*For googlers*: your Activity should inherit **AppCompatActivity**, not Activity

Comment: Thank you for noticing that!

Comment: Also, make sure you're calling `viewModels()` with a lowercase v, *not* `ViewModels()`

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use `val` and not `var` for your **ViewModel** property if you get error of cannot find setter.

Answer (score 2):

The extension function viewModels(...) was added in version [1.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-alpha03). Therefore, in order to use it in your app you will have to implement the fragment-ktx of versions matching 1.1.0-alpah03 or later.

I just found out about this and so I resorted to using version [1.1.0-rc01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-rc01) because I didn't want to use alpha/beta versions.

Comment: can't use it with **1.2.0-alpha02**

Answer (score 2):

You can implementation

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
```

In fact, the BY viewModels implementation in the KTX package looks like this, and you might as well implement an extension function yourself

```
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
        noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        val application = application ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(
                "ViewModel can be accessed only when Activity is attached"
        )
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
    }

    return ViewModelLazy(VM::class, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It works for me.

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by implementing the `fragment-ktx` library like this

```
def fragment_version = "1.4.0"

implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version")
```

See more and check latest version [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment).

Answer (score 0):

this happened because you forgot to add this dependency.

to solve this issue add this dependency

```
 implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'
```

and hit Sync

Answer (score -6):

**If you have come here looking for a solution for Koin**:

Note you can use use Koin to make this work:

`private val viewModel by viewModel<NoteViewModel>()`

would use the import

`import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel`

from the dependency:

`implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:+"` // change + to w/e is the latest when u read this

Comment: (answer cos I was looking myself, and google sent me here!)

Comment: yes, it's very tricky to have the right imports when using `koin` but this question is not related to koin.

Comment: The question came up on Google when searching for Koin problems, (same symptoms) so you never know :)

Comment: Why is Koin necessary?

Comment: Koin has the same api. So it's not necessary, its an alternative with the same problem.

Comment: I just think you would get better acknowledge of your answer if you explain why you're suggesting coin in the answer itself instead of comments.