# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY` ViewModel & Room

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am facing an issue while integrating Hilt with my view Model. The application gets crash right away after the launch. Any will be appreciated because I may be making a basic mistake.

```kotlin
//Here is my code for MainActivity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NoteJetTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
//                val noteViewModel = viewModel<NoteViewModel>()
                val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModels()
                NoteApp(noteViewModel = noteViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//and here's the viewModel code:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class NoteViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repo : NoteRepo): ViewModel() {
var \_noteList = MutableStateFlow\<List\<UserNote\>\>(emptyList())
var noteList = \_noteList.asStateFlow()

    init {
      //  noteList.addAll(NoteDataSource().loadNotes())
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repo.getAllNotes().distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect{ listOfNote ->
                    if(listOfNote.isNotEmpty())
                        _noteList.value = listOfNote
                    else
                        Log.d("noteListFlow", "list is empty")
                }
        }
    }
```

These are the libraries that I used in this project.

```
// here are the libs
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```

Comment: I also saw this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302605/creationextras-must-have-a-value-by-saved-state-registry-owner-key
 but his issue was related to navigation ,I am not even using the navigation

Comment: Please include the `dependencies` block from your build.gradle as these APIs require a [minimum version of the AndroidX Activity library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0)

Comment: I have added the project libs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Lifecycle 2.5.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0):

> **ViewModel CreationExtras** - These extras are provided automatically by your Activity or Fragment when using [Activity 1.5.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.5.0) and [Fragment 1.5.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.5.0), respectively.

And looking at those [Activity 1.5.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.5.0):

> **CreationExtras Integration** - `ComponentActivity` now has the ability to provide a stateless ViewModelProvider.Factory via Lifecycle 2.5.0’s CreationExtras.

Since you are using `ComponentActivity`, you need to upgrade to Activity 1.5.0 or higher in order to use libraries like Hilt that require the new CreationExtras APIs.

```
// Use the latest stable version of activity-compose
// but any version 1.5.0 or higher will work
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @ianhanniballake. Your answer is right. but I also found a way around to solve this problem. It turns out issue was in the way I was initializing the viewModel `val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModels()`. As soon as I switched it to `val noteViewModel = viewModel<NoteViewModel>()`, my problem get resolved but I have also verified your answer and it is correct. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @ZakiSiddiqui Yes you are right. I got the issue fixed as per your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue but in my case the viewmodel was not getting created in Fragment. Adding dependency with Fragment-ktx helped resolve this issue. Here's the solution I found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853282/7521936