# Kotlin: Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into byte code with JVM target 1.6

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have an issue when trying to add a few dependencies to my kotlin spring project. I used the spring boot initializer to get a basic project running.

My problem: If I uncomment jackson or either Koin dependency then my build fails with the mentioned in the titile
Here is the build.gradle.kts file :

```
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.31"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.0.M4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.31"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
        exclude(group = "junit", module = "junit")
    }

    // jackson
    //implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+")

    // Koin
    //implementation("org.koin:koin-core:2.0.1")

    // Koin Test
    //implementation("org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

I Have already tried all the solutions from this previous question someone else asked: [Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988778/cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode-that-is-being-bui)

I already had the KotlinCompile jvmTarget option in there and it has been set in my build settings as well. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246275/4694013

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the answers to this are android specific - using kotlin to write a spring boot app isn't that well documented or supported but still awesome. This setting in intelij cleared this error for me - hope it helps someone, my kotlin compiler had a target set to 1.6:

[image]

Comment: but don't forget to restart IDEA after the change