# start a sequence of timer in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, timer

I am trying to create a tabata timer.
I managed to take the user input from an editText and to start one timer, which represents the preparation time.

When that preparation time is over I want to start the work time and then the resting time.
Later on I need to repeat the Worktime and Resttime for x times as the user gives the input.
But I am not able to figure it out.

MainActivity.kt:

```
        btn_Start_Timer.setOnClickListener() {
            val prepTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val workTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val restTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val numberOfRepetitions = Integer.parseInt(eT_Number_Repetitions.text.toString().trim());

            val Timer = object : CountDownTimer(prepTimeMillis, 1000) {

                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    tV_Total_Duration.setText("Preparation 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    tV_Total_Duration.setText("Preparation done!")
                }
            }

            timer.start()
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Workout_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Name of the Workout"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_Total_Repetitions" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_WorkoutName"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_Workout_Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Prepare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Preparation"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_WorkoutName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_PrepTime"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_Prepare" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Decrement_PrepTime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="-"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eT_PrepTime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_WorkoutName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Increment_PrepTime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="+"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eT_PrepTime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_WorkoutName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_WorkTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Working"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_PrepTime" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_Work_Time"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_WorkTime" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Decrement_WorkTime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="-"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eT_Work_Time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Decrement_PrepTime" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Increment_WorkTime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="+"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eT_Work_Time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Increment_PrepTime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Repetitions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Number of Repetitions"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_Rest_Time" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Decrement_Repetitions"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="-"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eT_Number_Repetitions"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Decrement_Rest" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Increment_Repetitions"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="+"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eT_Number_Repetitions"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Increment_Rest" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_Number_Repetitions"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_Repetitions" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Rest_Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Resting"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_Work_Time" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Decrement_Rest"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="-"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eT_Rest_Time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Decrement_WorkTime" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eT_Rest_Time"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_Rest_Time" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Increment_Rest"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:text="+"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eT_Rest_Time"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Increment_WorkTime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Total_Duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Duration 00:00:00"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Total_Repetitions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Repeated for x times"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_Total_Duration" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Start_Timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                android:text="Start now"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_Number_Repetitions" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Stop_Timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                android:text="STOP"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eT_Number_Repetitions" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT:

I managed to import the library.

But I get the following errors now:

`Suspend function 'countDown' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

`Unresolved reference: lifecycleScope`

`Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper 'jvm-target' option`

`No value passed for parameter 'handler'`

Code:

```
        btn_Start_Timer.setOnClickListener() {
            val prepTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val workTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_Work_Time.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val restTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_Rest_Time.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
            val numberOfRepetitions = Integer.parseInt(eT_Number_Repetitions.text.toString().trim());

            countdownJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
                repeat(numberOfRepetitions) {
                    countDown(prepTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                        tV_Total_Duration.setText("Preparation 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }
                    countDown(workTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                        tV_Total_Duration.setText("Work 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }
                    countDown(restTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                        tV_Total_Duration.setText("Rest 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        btn_Stop_Timer.setOnClickListener(){

        }
    }

    suspend inline fun countDown(millisInFuture: Long, countDownInterval: Long, crossinline onTick: (Long) -> Unit) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
    {
        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit>
        { continuation ->
            val timer = object: CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval)
            {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) = onTick(millisUntilFinished)
                override fun onFinish() = continuation.resume(Unit)
            }.start()

            continuation.invokeOnCancellation()
            {
                timer.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
build.gradle (Module.app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instafollow"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.4.0-rc01")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.4.0-rc01")
    testImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0")

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
}
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

EDIT:

I managed to change the target JVM to 1.8, and I have no more errors in my code.
But when I try to start the project, I Get a series of errors like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you would do this with the existing class is to nest another countdown timer inside the `onFinish()` of the first one and use that nested one to count down the work time. And then for the rest time you would nest another timer inside the `onFinish()` of that timer. But also, since you want to repeat the whole thing, you would have to move this into a separate function so you can call it repeatedly. So that function that starts the three timers would also need a countdown parameter. Very complicated, it would look something like this:

```
btn_Start_Timer.setOnClickListener() {
    val prepTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
    val workTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
    val restTimeMillis = Integer.parseInt(eT_PrepTime.text.toString().trim()) * 1000L;
    val numberOfRepetitions = Integer.parseInt(eT_Number_Repetitions.text.toString().trim());

    doRep(prepTimeMillis, workTimeMillis, restTimeMillis, numberOfRepetitions)
}

private fun doRep(prepTimeMillis: Long, workTimeMillis: Long, restTimeMillis: Long, times: Int) {
    object : CountDownTimer(prepTimeMillis, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            tV_Total_Duration.setText("Preparation 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            object : CountDownTimer(workTimeMillis, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    tV_Total_Duration.setText("Work 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    object : CountDownTimer(restTimeMillis, 1000) {
                        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                            tV_Total_Duration.setText("Rest 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                        }

                        override fun onFinish() {
                            if (times == 1) {
                                tV_Total_Duration.setText("All done!")
                            } else {
                                doRep(prepTimeMillis, workTimeMillis, restTimeMillis, times - 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }.start()
                }
            }.start()
        }
    }.start()

}
```

This is what is nicknamed "callback hell", where you have to nest code deeply and it is hard to follow, so it is a prime candidate for simplifying with coroutines. Here is a suspend function version of CountdownTimer that lets you use it sequentially instead of by nesting code. When you call this function in a coroutine, you pass it the action you would have normally put in the `onTick` function. It automatically starts the timer, and then the coroutine suspends until `onFinish()` happens, so your coroutine code can be written sequentially. If the coroutine that called it is cancelled, it will cancel the timer so `onTick()` stops getting called.

```
suspend inline fun countDown(
    millisInFuture: Long,
    countDownInterval: Long,
    crossinline onTick: (Long) -> Unit
) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit>{ continuation ->
        val timer = object: CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) = onTick(millisUntilFinished)
            override fun onFinish() = continuation.resume(Unit)
        }.start()
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation { timer.cancel() }
    }
}
```

I would also create a simple helper function to get your user input from the edit text and avoid code duplication, like this:

```
fun TextView.inputToInt(): Long = text.toString().trim().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

With these two functions, you can write your code in the button listener sequentially using a launched coroutine:

```
btn_Start_Timer.setOnClickListener() {
    val prepTimeMillis = eT_PrepTime.inputToInt() * 1000L
    val workTimeMillis = eT_PrepTime.inputToInt() * 1000L // TODO pick correct ET
    val restTimeMillis = eT_PrepTime.inputToInt() * 1000L // TODO pick correct ET
    val numberOfRepetitions = eT_Number_Repetitions.inputToInt()
    
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeat(numberOfRepetitions) {
            countDown(prepTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                tV_Total_Duration.setText("Preparation 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }    
            countDown(workTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                tV_Total_Duration.setText("Work 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }    
            countDown(restTimeMillis, 1000L) { millisUntilFinished ->
                tV_Total_Duration.setText("Rest 00:00: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your design is susceptible to the timer being reset every time the screen rotates, because the Activity will be destroyed and recreated. I suggest putting the timer inside a ViewModel that updates a `LiveData<String>` with a value that can be observed in the Activity to apply to the TextView. But that is a huge topic. You can read up in the documentation about how to use ViewModel and LiveData.

**Edit:**
To support cancellation, you need a property to hold the coroutine job.

```
private var countdownJob: Job? = null
```

When you want to cancel a current countdown if one exists, use null-safe cancel:

```
countdownJob?.cancel()
```

When you launch the coroutine, assign its Job to this variable:

```
countdownJob = lifecycleScope.launch { 
   // ... code from above example
}
```

Comment: How can we cancel the timer in this solution if there was a button to cancel or the user enters another data and want to start again. Thanks

Comment: I had to write a new answer because it didn't have enough space in a comment...sry for that.

Comment: Sry the xy should have been the placeholder for ```lifecycleScope.launch```,```suspendCancellableCoroutine```,```withContext(Dispatchers.Main)```. Regarding the code, i copied all of it and changed the things you commented as ```TODO```

Comment: I think you are simply missing the coroutines library. Add `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'` to your build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: I added my errors now to the initial question. I am not able to solve them

Comment: Make sure you have the `-ktx` versions of the Jetpack lifecycle libraries in your dependencies. [See here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

Comment: Added those too, the only error that vanished is ```No value passed for parameter 'handler'```. The others are the same.

Comment: I don't know what else could be wrong. Maybe you could share your `build.gradle` from the app module so we can see if something's missing. It's weird that it's complaining about JVM target or that you're missing -ktx libraries in the first place if you started your project as a new one in a recent version of Android Studio.

Comment: I added the build.gradle files.

Comment: You didn't use the `-ktx` versions of the Jetpack lifecycle libraries like I suggested. Specifically, you need to use `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` instead of `lifecycle-runtime`. You did not need to add additional libraries that you were not using. Those will slow down your build time.

Comment: Allright, did that too, now the only error I get is the JVM target one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988778/cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode-that-is-being-bui

Comment: Managed to change the JVM target, but I have way more errors when I start the project. I think I have to restart from the begginning here...Edited the inital question

Comment: Maybe you have a very out-of-date Android Studio version or your Kotlin plugin is very out of date. I don't know. When I create a new project in Android Studio, it is already set up with the correct libraries and Gradle version.

Comment: I indeed completely updated android studio to the latest version, now it is working...Thank you!