# React Native jvm target compatibility issue

Tags: android, react-native

First of all, i am new in React Native. 
When i build my empty(completely new) project it gives an error;

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> 'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

```
I found a solution the above problem but i couldn't find the location that they mention. 
Where are these code locations? Btw They say that;

**set java version for java;** 
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

**set jvmTarget;**
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to put this in build.gradle, it doesn't exist by default. android\app\build.gradle

Comment: it gives an error like this; [ddms]: ADB rejected shell command (am get-config): closed

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to do it like the following:

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

Reference: [Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988778/cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode-that-is-being-bui)

Comment: it gives that error; No signature of method: build_1nk6ipvtttnyo5e029w02qoxd.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1nk6ipvtttnyo5e029w02qoxd$_run_closure1) values: [build_1nk6ipvtttnyo5e029w02qoxd$_run_closure1@3dad5683]

Comment: any solution @CüneytKılıç

Comment: When i restart pc, my problem solved