# Updating a Kotlin Multiplatform project from JVM target 1.8 to 11?

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform with Precompose as the navigation library. When I do the following snippet to navigate with variables passed across:

```kotlin
scene(
    route = NavigationDestination.TodoDetailed.route + "/{id}",
) { backStackEntry: BackStackEntry ->
    val id: String? = backStackEntry.path("id")

    TodoDetailedView(
        vm = TodoDetailedViewModel(jsonData = id!!),
        onNavigateBack = { navigator.goBack() }
    )
}
```

and then build it I get the following error:

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 11 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

The line that is highlighted is `backStackEntry.path("id")`.

I have the following build.gradle.kts file:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.realm)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.22"
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "11"
            }
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api(compose.foundation)
            api(compose.animation)
            api(libs.precompose)
            api(libs.precompose.viewmodel)
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(libs.androidx.animation)
            implementation(libs.androidx.material.icons.extended)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
            implementation(libs.co.touchlab.kermit)
            implementation(libs.kotlin.realm.library.base)
            implementation(libs.kotlin.realm.library.sync)
        } 
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.sycosoft"
    compileSdkVersion(libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt())

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sycosoft"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.sycosoft"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried to change bits that show 1.8 to 11 with no success so how would I update it to be using the JVM target of 11 instead of 1.8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988778/cannot-inline-bytecode-built-with-jvm-target-1-8-into-bytecode-that-is-being-bui)

Comment: I tried to change ```compileOptions``` from ```JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8``` to ```JavaVersion.VERSION_11``` and it hasn't worked. Still displays the same error. It also says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with android studio(in my case to java 17), open "Project Structure" on "File > Project Structrure"
[image]

Select the section "modules" on composeApp and shared, change the Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility to JavaVersion 11 in your case
[image]

In my case i get error on build.gradle because android studio didnt changed wll with variables, and i changed Version17 to
JavaVersion.VERSION_17 on build.gradle
[image]